# How to vertically align the three columns of my table top, top, middle

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, columns

I would like the formulae in the third column to be vertically aligned to the middle, i.e. the formulae should be vertically at the middle of the two lines of the descriptions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \caption{I would like the formulae here to be vertically at the middle of the two lines of text}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX>{$}c<{$}}
        \toprule
        Name & Description & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Formula}\\
        \midrule
        Ducks & Something which goes on two lines, something which goes on two lines &
        A=\dfrac{B}{C}\\
        Lions & Something which goes on two lines, something which goes on two lines &
        D=\dfrac{E}{F}\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \caption{Here the formulae are correctly aligned with the description, but I would like the name at the top like in the previous table}
    \begin{tabular}{lm{24em}>{$}c<{$}}
        \toprule
        Name & Description & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Formula}\\
        \midrule
        Ducks & Something which goes on two lines, something which goes on two lines &
        A=\dfrac{B}{C}\\
        Lions & Something which goes on two lines, something which goes on two lines &
        D=\dfrac{E}{F}\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by  ‘vertically aligned’? For me, they are.

Comment: @Bernard I would like the formulae to be vertically at the middle of the two lines of text

Comment: Do you want the first column top-aligned?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, exactly!

Comment: @Bernard I've edited my question, please see if it's clearer now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here a solution based on the redefinition of the `X` column type, and two possible hacks for the first column (they may have to be adapted to the real contents):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs, makecell}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX>{$}c<{$}}
        \toprule
        Name & Description & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Formula}\\
        \midrule
       \makecell[l]{Ducks\\\mbox{}} & Something which goes on two lines, something which goes on two lines &
        A=\dfrac{B}{C}\\
\addlinespace
        \makecell[l]{Lions\\\mbox{}} & Something which goes on two lines, something which goes on two lines &
        D=\dfrac{E}{F}\\
\addlinespace
       \raisebox{1.4ex}{Lions} & Something which goes on two lines, something which goes on two lines &
        D=\dfrac{E}{F}\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It not cross my mind to move contents in cell's of the first column +1!

Comment: add a third line to one of the cells ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: in the `X` column?

Comment: yes, naturally there.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: it seems to centre the `X` column w.r.t. the maths axis of the last column. Don't see what to do in such situations but case by case  hacks (dirtier and dirtier!).

Comment: Eventually, I used the `\makecell[l]{#1\\\mbox{}}` trick. It is the simplest one, also because if I want to align the last column to the equals, I can't use Zarko's solution.

Comment: For more complex formulæ in the last column, my solution is far from perfect. See the comments above. If the text in the  `X`column is longer, you only have to add the relevant number of line breaks. Perhaps, it would be worth  defining a macro for that.

Comment: @Bernard I know your solution is not perfect, but my formulae are all simple fractions and the text is always two lines, so your solution works. I created this macro `\newcommand{\fakealign}[1]{\makecell[l]{#1\\\mbox{}}}`. Maybe an alternative simple solution is nesting `tabulars`, as Ulrike said, but I'm too lazy and if a simple solution works in a peculiar case, why don't use it? :):):)

Comment: I quite agree with your point of view (as Oscar Wilde said (I quote roughly): why make things simple when it's so simple to make them complex? ;o)

Answer (score 7):

This is rather hard: the problem is that you want to align the middle box in two ways: on the left along the baseline, on the right along the center. This type of table normally requires either nesting of tables (which is difficult with tabularx) or measuring some of the content to use \llap tricks.

We are missing here tabular code based on xcoffins which has more than one handle ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{caption,xcoffins}
\newlength\colA

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
    \settowidth\colA{\begin{tabular}{l}Name\\Ducks\\Lions\end{tabular}}
    \caption{I would like the formulae here to be vertically at the middle of the two lines of text}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{\dimexpr\colA-2\tabcolsep}X>{$}c<{$}}
        \toprule
        Name & Description & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Formula}\\
        \midrule
             &\leavevmode\llap{\makebox[\colA][l]{Ducks}}Something which goes on two lines, something which goes on two lines &
        A=\dfrac{B}{C}\\
             &\leavevmode\llap{\makebox[\colA][l]{Lions}}Something which goes on two lines, something which goes on two lines and on one more line and on one more line and on one more line &
        D=\dfrac{E}{F}\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

%Only for show some coffin code:

\NewCoffin\CoffinA
\NewCoffin\CoffinB
\NewCoffin\CoffinC

\SetHorizontalCoffin\CoffinA{Ducks}
\SetHorizontalCoffin\CoffinC{$D=\dfrac{E}{F}$}

\SetVerticalCoffin\CoffinB{\dimexpr \textwidth-\CoffinWidth\CoffinA-\CoffinWidth\CoffinC-6\tabcolsep}{\noindent Something which goes on two lines, something which goes on two lines and on one more line and on one more line and on one more line}

\JoinCoffins\CoffinA[H,r]\CoffinB[T,l](2\tabcolsep,0pt)
\JoinCoffins\CoffinA[vc,r]\CoffinC[vc,l](2\tabcolsep,0pt)
\noindent\hspace*{\tabcolsep}\TypesetCoffin\CoffinA
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

[image]

**Edit:**

Position of columns contents are determined by row baseline, which (unfortunately)  cannot be changed from column to column.

So far I don't see any other possibility than to use boxes either in the last or the first column, which align their baseline. A good candidate for your particular case is `\adjustbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \caption{I would like the formulae here to be vertically at the middle of the two lines of text}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXc}
        \toprule
        Name & Description & Formula    \\
        \midrule
        Ducks & Something which goes on two lines, something which goes on two lines &
        \adjustbox{valign=t}{$A=\dfrac{B}{C}$}\\
        Lions & Something which goes on two lines, something which goes on two lines &
        \adjustbox{valign=t}{$D=\dfrac{E}{F}$}\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

For more convenient writing of the table, you can define a new column type:

```
\newcolumntype{E}{>{\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}$}c<{$\end{adjustbox}}}
```

and then write the table (body) as:

```
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXE}
        \toprule
        Name & Description & Formula    \\
        \midrule
        Ducks & Something which goes on two lines, something which goes on two lines &
        A=\dfrac{B}{C}\\
        Lions & Something which goes on two lines, something which goes on two lines &
        D=\dfrac{E}{F}\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
```

If the text in cells of the middle column has arbitrary number of lines, or if the equation has only one line, the result is worse. In such case a possible solution is the use of `multirow` in the first column and manually adjust the number of columns which those cells spans, and in the second column set baseline in vertical middle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}} % <---
    \caption{I would like the formulae here to be vertically at the middle of the two lines of text}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX>{$}c<{$}}
        \toprule
        Name & Description & Formula    \\
        \midrule
\multirow{-6}{*}{Ducks} % <--- manually adjusted
      & \lipsum[66] & A=\dfrac{B}{C}\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or use solution proposed in @Bernard's answer.

Comment: Quite ingenious! (+1)

Comment: Unfortunately, it only *appears* to work because 1) there are only two lines in the texts of the second column and 2) the formulas have *this particular height.* Try with either `\lipsum[1]` in the second column or with `$A=B$` for either of the formulas. (Yes, the question is a tough one, and I did upvote it.)

Comment: My actual table is like the mock one, so your solution works. Now I have to decide which one to use (both already upvoted).

Comment: @CarLaTeX, thank you for editing my answer.Since in the same time i wrote some more explanation and add new example, I will very glad if you correct my answer again. Well, which answer you will choose, is up to you :-).

Comment: @Zarko I edited it only because there was "shoved" instead of "showed" :):):) I'm not a native English speaker, so I rarely correct

Answer (score 1):

To have a complete picture of the possibilities, I include a table typeset with the help of [cals](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cals). It is very easy to have such alignments using a `calstable`. I have removed left and right side bearing, which add code, not strictly necessary for creating OP’s table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cals, caption, amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\caption{I would like the formulae here to be vertically at the middle of the two lines of text}
\begin{calstable}[c]
% Defining columns relative to each other and relative to the margins
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/6\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/6*4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/6\relax}
            }

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.8pt}   % Outside frame rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.6pt}
\def\cals@cs@width{0pt}             % Inside rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@rs@width{0.4pt}

\def\bb{\ifx\cals@borderB\relax     % Botton border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderB{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderB\relax\fi}

\def\lp{\ifdim\cals@paddingL=0.0pt\relax    % Left padding switch (off-on)
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\else \setlength{\cals@paddingL}{0pt}\fi}

\def\rp{\ifdim\cals@paddingR=0.0pt\relax    % Right padding switch (off-on)
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\else \setlength{\cals@paddingR}{0pt}\fi}


% R1H1
\thead{\small%
\brow
    \lp\alignL\cell{Name}\lp
    \alignL\cell{Description}
    \rp\alignR\cell{Formula}\rp
\erow
\normalsize%
}
\tfoot{\lastrule\strut}
%R2B1
\brow
    \lp\bb\alignL\cell{Ducks}\lp
    \alignL\cell{Something which goes on two lines, something which goes on two lines}
    \rp\alignR\cell{\vfil$A=\dfrac{B}{C}$}\rp
\erow
%R3B2
\brow
    \bb\lp\alignL\cell{Gnus}\lp
    \alignL\cell{Something which goes on two lines, something which goes on two lines and on one more line and on one more line and on one more line}
    \rp\alignR\cell{\vfil$D=\dfrac{E}{F}$}\rp\bb
\erow
%R4B3
\brow
    \lp\alignL\cell{Gnats}\lp
    \alignL\cell{Something which goes on two lines, something which goes on two lines and on one more line and on one more line and on one more line}
    \rp\alignR\cell{\vfil $D=\dfrac{E}{F}$}\rp
\erow
\makeatletter
\end{calstable}\par
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```